# How can I use as a data source for a XAML element, only rows of a Child DataSet Table that refer to a specific ID on a Parent Table?

Tags: c#, sql, wpf, database, xaml

In simpler terms: How do I reference only the child table rows in a XAML view that refer to a parent ID?

I know how to use a DataSet adapter to populate it from a database table and create a listview/treeview/etc. with it. Now, I have added a new table that its main ID column is linked with a Relation to the parent table's ID. How can I make a view in XAML that is populated only by the children of that new table according to one ID on the parent table and not by all the entries of the child table?

The way I use the main table now is simply:

1. Assign table adapter
2. Fill() the DataSet with the table
3. Fill a DataGrid (for instance) with a simple viewsource that references Source="{Binding Path=The_Main_Table, Source={StaticResource dataSet1}}"

So the question is, now that I have a child table connected with a Relation (connecting an ID column between the two), how to populate a DataGrid for instance ONLY with the child rows that refer to a selected row on the Parent table? The selection of the Parent row has already been done and a reference to it can be done either with XAML or code-behind.

Comment: Have you looked at https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/windows/desktop/c12c1kx4(v=vs.80).aspx ?

Answer (score 0):

OK, the answer I will provide (for my own question), is not very technically detailed by I believe it will be great help for other beginners on this. Basically what you do is that you open the **Data Sources** window, then you find the table that acts as a Parent, scroll down and find the entry that represents the Related table and simply drag-and-drop it onto a XAML Designer container which will provide a good example usage for that kind of data binding because it will automatically create a GridView (or ListView etc. depended on choice).

An image from the official documentation *Display related data in WPF applications*:

[image]

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/display-related-data-in-wpf-applications

Now, that is not enough for it to automatically switch to the Parent's selected row, however you will notice that one of the entries might be already restricted properly.

Only thing you have to do now is to use methods such 
 as

```
myParentTableViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToPosition(i);
```

And the view based on the Parent ViewSource will automatically change.

**Behind the scenes:**

The basic reason this works is that instead of using as a source the entire dataset, the view binds directly to the Relation and the source of it is the Parent table's viewsource..

Just read how the drag and dropped element is coded and you'll be set.